# IndexOutOfBounds error

Tags: c#

So I'm new to programming. I have printed two arrays next to each other. On the left column, I have Ace,2,3,4.. up until Jack, Queen king. One the right column is my suites. So Clubs, hearts etc. Now I want to randomize my whole deck, but I find only for example 3 Hearts print, nothing else. Also, I get an `IndexOutOfBounds` error.I can't figure out why.

Here's my code:

```
string[] suites = new string[] { "hearts", "clubs", "diamonds", "spades" };

string [] pack = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13" };

Random r = new Random();
string[] x = new string[] { suites[r.Next(0,3)].ToString() };
string[] y = new string[] { pack[r.Next(0,12)].ToString() };

for (int a = 0; a < 13; a++)
{
    for (int p = 0; p < 4; p++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(y[a] + " " + x[p]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How many elements are in the x and y arrays? Don't answer to this question ...yet. First, use the debugger to confirm -- or contradict -- your assumption...

Comment: Random r = new Random();
            string[] x = new string[] { suites[r.Next(0,3)].ToString() };
            string[] y = new string[] { pack[r.Next(0,12)].ToString() }; Sorry guys. I missed this piece of code before my for loop.

Comment: `x` and `y` will always contain only one element

Comment: what is debugger?

Comment: You have homework: Learn what a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) is and how to use the debugger in Visual Studio. Briefly, the debugger is among the **most useful** tools to trouble-shoot and understand what your code is actually doing...

Comment: Okey. Thank you.

Comment: Also you might want to consider creating an actual card class with the suite and value as properties then create a deck from that, especially if you need to avoid duplicate cards.

Comment: The debugger Wikipedia link i have given in my previous comment -- forget it. Oh man, that Wikipedia article is terse and gets lost in minutiae while forgetting to explain properly the purpose/utility of it. Perhaps start with some Visual Studio Debugger tutorial, something like this perhaps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger

Comment: You just select one element randomly from array an put it in new arrays called x & y , so they have just one random selected element not random clone of original arrays, if you want to randomize your array you can do it like this :

string[] y = pack.OrderBy(xx => r.Next()).ToArray();

Comment: And after you have made this work, throw it away and look up the Fisher-Yates shuffle.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Totally agree, even if the OP gets the two arrays randomized the resulting nested loops will just give results where cards of the save value are grouped together in the same suite order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace below lines

```
string[] x = new string[] { suites[r.Next(0,3)].ToString() };
string[] y = new string[] { pack[r.Next(0,12)].ToString() };
```

With

```
string[] x = suites.OrderBy(a => r.Next()).ToArray();
string[] y = pack.OrderBy(a => r.Next()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked out well and I have learned something new. :-)

Comment: In regards to debugging. I have read through that as well. It will assist me in programming.